# Continuous Ping Powershell Form

Tags: forms, winforms, user-interface, powershell

OK so I am newer to using windows forms inside Powershell, and I am having a bit of trouble with the form being all laggy since there is a continuous ping running. Fundamentally all I need to do is display the IP address each time it runs a ping. I tried to search around and it seems like the proper way to do this is with a running job in the background?

I think the way this is currently written that the ping happens in the background but I'm not sure how to update the form (or if its even possible to make it visible to it?)

Here is a sample, any guidance with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
function global:ContinuousPing{
    $global:job = start-job {
        while($true){
            $pingStatus = Test-Connection google.com -Count 1
            $label.text = $pingStatus.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
            #[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()
            start-sleep 1
        }
    }
}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$pingForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button

$ping = {
    ContinuousPing

    while($true){
        Receive-Job $job
    }
}

$label.Text = "Ping Status"

$button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(100,10)
$button1.add_Click($ping)

$pingForm.Controls.Add($label)
$pingForm.Controls.Add($button1)

$pingForm.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

remove-job $job
```

Comment: You'll need to dispatch the ping to a background thread, maybe have a look at [WPFRunspace](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/WPFRunspace-a-BackgroundWor-7f30edc4)

Comment: What powershell version are you running?

Comment: Powershell version 3

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate the GUI updating and the ping task. This is easy to in languages that are designed to have GUIs like C# winforms, If you tried it you would be surprised how much easier it is than trying to bend a GUI over PowerShell.

You can try the link Mathias posted, It will do what you require.

Comment: On top of that, there are plenty of ping classes out there, and you could always host a Runspace from PowerShell and run Test-Connection if you're really intent on using that instead.

Comment: Anything native for Powershell that I could use instead?

Comment: Native out of the box PowerShell? not that I have ever heard of. I love PowerShell and you can do anything you want with it, But it can get really difficult with GUI stuff. Your scripts can be come monolithic huge sections of GUI code that makes it really hard for other people to support your scripts and documentation to get massive as well.